# How to populate an empty XML node using modify replace on an XML column?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, sql-update, xquery, sqlxml

This is my xml stored in an XML type column called UserDef

```
<Orders>
  <Document>
    <DocumentID>abc123</DocumentID>
    <ActualShipDate />
    <Comments/>
  </Document>
  <Document>
 ....
 ...
  </Document>
</Orders>
```

I'm trying to populate the `Comments` element with this:

```
declare @t1 table (id bigint, userdef xml)

insert into @t1
select id, userdef from MyMainTable

update @t1 
set userdef.modify('replace value of(/Orders/Document/Comments[1]/text())[1]  with "NO COMMENTS"')
select * from @t1
```

However, I don't see the `Comments` being populated at all. What should I do differently in order for this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Element `<Comments/>` has no `text()` node, you should do `insert` rather then `replace`:

```
    update @t1 
    set userdef.modify('
        insert text{"NO COMMENTS"}
        into (/Orders/Document/Comments[1])[1]
    ')
    where id = @id;
```

If one wishes to insert text from sql variable, the following construct can be used:

```
declare @comments varchar(1000);
set @comments = 'NO COMMENTS';

update @t1 
set userdef.modify('
    insert text {sql:variable("@comments")}
    into (/Orders/Document/Comments[1])[1]
')
where id = @id;
```

Comment: What if I wanted to insert a variable in the INSERT statement? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32253235/how-to-use-if-else-statement-to-update-or-create-new-xml-node-entry-in-sql Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. You are a life saver.