# How to use IF/ELSE statement to update or create new xml node entry in Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

Example:

```
<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Lopez, Michelle MD</Value1>
        <Value2>Spanish</Value2>
        <Value3>
            <a title="49 west point" href="myloc.aspx?id=56" target="_blank">49 west point</a>
        </Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>
            <a title="CM" href="myspec.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">CM</a>
        </Value5>
        <Value6 /> /* No anchor link exist, but I would like to add the same format as Value5 */
    </StartOne>
</root>
```

Sql (currently only sees if the anchor link already exist and updates):

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Declare @xml xml;
    Select @xml = cast([content_html] as xml)
    From [Db1].[dbo].[zTable]

    Declare @locID varchar(200);
    Declare @locTitle varchar(200);
    Declare @locUrl varchar(255);

    Select @locID = t1.content_id From [westmedWebDB-bk].[dbo].[zTempLocationTable] t1
    INNER JOIN [Db1].[dbo].[zTableFromData] t2 On t2.Value3 = t1.content_title
    Where t2.Value1 = @ProviderName --@ProviderName is a parameter

    Select @locTitle = t1.content_title From [Db1].[dbo].[zTempLocationTable] t1
    Where @locID = t1.content_id

    Set @locUrl = 'theloc.aspx?id=' + @locID + '';

    --if Value5 has text inside...

    Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value5/a/text())[1] with sql:variable("@locTitle")');
    Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value5/a/@title)[1] with sql:variable("@locTitle")');
    Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value56/a/@href)[1] with sql:variable("@locUrl")');

     --otherwise... create a new anchor

     set @locAnchor = ('<a href="theloc.aspx?id=' + @locID + '" title="' + @locTitle + '">' + @locTitle + '</a>');

     set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value1/text())[1] with sql:variable("@locAnchor")'); --this adds "&lt;" and "&gt;" instead of "<" and ">" is the issue

    Update [Db1].[dbo].[zTable]
    Set [content_html] = cast(@xml as nvarchar(max))
    Where [content_title] = @ProviderName --@ProviderName is a parameter
END
```

How can I modify it so, if the anchor link already exist, update. Otherwise create a new anchor link with the `<` and `>` instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Update: This is working for me now (Not sure if there is a more efficient method)

```
If @xml.exist('/root/StartOne/Value6/a/text()') = 1 --if there is an anchor link/text in the node
    BEGIN
        --modify the text of the link
        Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value6/a/text())[1] with sql:variable("@locTitle")');

        --modify the title of the link
        Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value6/a/@title)[1] with sql:variable("@locTitle")');

        --modify the url of the link
        Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value6/a/@href)[1] with sql:variable("@locUrl")');
    END
Else --otherwise create a new anchor link
    BEGIN
        --Set @locAnchor = ('<a href="theloc.aspx?id=' + @locID + '" title="' + @locTitle + '">' + @locTitle + '</a>');

        --Set @xml.modify('insert <a title="Value6" href="Value6.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">Value6</a> into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]');
        declare @a  xml;
        Set @a = N'<a title="' + @locTitle+ '" href="' +@locUrl+ '" target="_blank">'+@locTitle+'</a>';
        Set @xml.modify('insert sql:variable("@a") into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]');
    END
```

Comment: yes kool it seems fine :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete the anchor element first and then insert the new one. It does not matter if it is there or not for the delete statement. I also provided a better way to build your new anchor element. It takes care of creating entities for characters like `&`.

```sql
-- Delete the anchor node from the XML
set @xml.modify('delete /root/StartOne/Value6/a');

-- Build the XML for the new anchor node
set @a = (
         select @locTitle as 'a/@title',
                @locUrl as 'a/@href',
                '_blank' as 'a/@target',
                @locTitle as 'a'
         for xml path(''), type
         );

-- Insert the new anchor node
set @xml.modify('insert sql:variable("@a") into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]');
```

Comment: What should `a` be declared as? Thank you.

Comment: @SiKni8  It should be `XML`

Comment: Just figured it out but you beat me to it. Thank you. This is much simpler actually.

Comment: I guess this will eliminate the need for if/else statement? Just have the above which should handle if there is Anchor that exist or if it doesn't. Will the `delete` give an error if nothing exist or just go to the next code?

Comment: This actually worked great so far. Thank you. I +1 and accepted your answer because it was the easiest solution to implement. Thanks again.

Comment: I am running into some issue. Can I ask it here?

Comment: @sikni8 if ask a new question on site more people will see it and can answer. Please post a link to the new question here so I can find it.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this will help you

```
Declare @locUrl varchar(255);
Set @locUrl = 'xyz.aspx?id=' + '444' + '';

declare @xml xml;
set @xml = '<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Lopez, Michelle MD</Value1>
        <Value2>Spanish</Value2>
        <Value3>
            <a title="49 west point" href="myloc.aspx?id=56" target="_blank">49 west point</a>
        </Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>
            <a title="CM" href="myspec.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">CM</a>
        </Value5>
        <Value6>
        </Value6>
    </StartOne>
</root>';

declare @chk nvarchar(max);
-- here implementing for Value6
set @chk = (select 
C.value('(Value6/a/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') col
from
@xml.nodes('/root/StartOne') as X(C))
-- make sure here 
select @chk;


if @chk is null
begin
-- INSERT
SET @xml.modify('       
insert <a title="Value6" href="Value6.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">Value6</a> 
into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]') 
end

else
begin
-- UPDATE
Set @xml.modify('replace value of (/root/StartOne/Value6/a/@href)[1] with sql:variable("@locUrl")');
end

select @xml
```

UPDATE: after your below comment this is the way to update dynamically

```
Declare @locUrl nvarchar(255);
Set @locUrl = 'xyz.aspx?id=' + '444' + '';

declare @xml xml;
set @xml = '<root>
    <StartOne>
        <Value1>Lopez, Michelle MD</Value1>
        <Value2>Spanish</Value2>
        <Value3>
            <a title="49 west point" href="myloc.aspx?id=56" target="_blank">49 west point</a>
        </Value3>
        <Value4>908-783-0909</Value4>
        <Value5>
            <a title="CM" href="myspec.aspx?id=78" target="_blank">CM</a>
        </Value5>
        <Value6>
        </Value6>
    </StartOne>
</root>';

declare @a  xml;
set @a = N'<a title="' + @locUrl+ '" href="' +@locUrl+ '" target="_blank">'+@locUrl+'</a>';

SET @xml.modify
('insert sql:variable("@a")
into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]');

select @xml;
```

Comment: Trying to use variable for the INSERT statement here: `SET @xml.modify('Insert <a title="sql:variable("@locTitle")" href="sql:variable("@locUrl")" target="_blank">sql:variable("@locTitle")</a> Into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]') ;` but it's not working for me. Error: `XQuery [modify()]: Syntax error near 'a'`

Comment: This didn't work either: `Set @locAnchor = ('<a href="theloc.aspx?id=' + @locID + '" title="' + @locTitle + '">' + @locTitle + '</a>');
Set @xml.modify('insert sql:variable("@locAnchor") into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]');` Error: `XQuery [modify()]: Only non-document nodes can be inserted. Found "xs:string ?".`

Comment: `Set @xml.modify('insert xs:string(sql:variable("@locAnchor")) into (/root/StartOne/Value6)[1]');` didn't work either.

Comment: @SiKni8 SORRY for delay please check updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you. How can I clear out the stuff inside `Value6` before inserting (If it exists)? I am sorry to ask so many questions but I am starting this out. If I run it multiple times, it will just keep appending. I would like it to clear out anything prior to inserting.

Comment: I actually took care of it with an IF/Else statement... I updated my question to show you what I did. Let me know if it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to just try replacing:

```
set @locAnchor = ('<a href="theloc.aspx?id=' + 
@locID + '" title="' + @locTitle + '">' + 
@locTitle + '</a>');
```

with:

```
SELECT @locAnchor = (SELECT 'theloc.aspx?id=' + @locID AS 'Value6/a/@href',
@locTitle AS 'Value6/a/@title',
@locTitle AS 'Value6/a'
FOR XML PATH (''))
```

instead of trying to dynamically create the XML